# how to open Help Window in eclipse from Browser

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Suppose I've a browser carrying a static html file.

> Now I've a hyperlink in the provided
>   html and onn clicking that link I want
>   to open the Help standalone window of
>   eclipse.

What is the way to do. In Eclipse welcome page, this scenario is already there but couldn't justify my requirment.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to open Eclipse's standalone help from a browser? Why not open it in the browser itself? The URL would be something like: http://127.0.0.1:4874/help/index.jsp

You can also launch Eclipse's standalone help from the command line:

```
cd $ECLIPSE_HOME
java -cp plugins\org.eclipse.help.base_3.4.0.v201002111343.jar org.eclipse.help.standalone.Help -command displayhelp
```

You can probably put this command in a script or bat file, but you won't be able to run it from your browser, unless you write an Applet or use ActiveX. However, this is not recommended because it breaks security.

Comment: Then how in eclipse welcome page, it opens the help menu on clicking on a selected hyperlink.how that is working?

Comment: One more addition.I already opened the webpage in eclipse browser. Now in that webpage, I have a hyperlink in which the action should prompt me the eclipse help menu.

Comment: Can you suggest me any solution for the problem I am facing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette